# matching algorithm between a collection(Xi) and a collection(collection(Yj))

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, matching

I need a matching algorithm between a collection(Xi) and a collection(collection(Yj))

knowing that  Collection()Yj  may have elements in common

I explain with an example:

suppose we have a web service S with 3 inputs (I1,I2,I3)

I1 can be provided by services A, B, C, D
I2 can be provided by service   A,E
I3 can be provided by services F

I need an algorithm or a function to find the best combinaison between the available services(A to F) to provide the input of S (I1,I2,I3)

Collection(Xi)={I1,I2,I3}

Collection(Collection(Yj))= {{A,B,C,D},{A,E},{F}}

Thank you.

Comment: "Best" by what metric?

Comment: I think this problem is similar to finding shortest paths in an and/Or graph. 
as a metric, we can affect a weight to each matching (a function of many parameters such semantique similarities, quality of services....)

I1->A have a the weight Wa
I1->B  (Wb)
..

to simplify we can consider all the weight =1

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you done any research on algorithms? Have you tried to write any code?

Comment: I'm exploring several tracks to try to fit my problematic well  and see if this is going to be a bipartite graph problem or an and/or or...   and find the right algorithm. I 

I asked the question here to see if anyone can give me some help

Comment: @hajarelmaghraoui If all the weights are 1, can you not just choose an arbitrary element of each set in Y?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly the explanation of Maximum Bipartite Matching problem.
One part is {i1, i2, i3 .....}, the other part is {A, B, C, D, ....}

Read more about it here.
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-bipartite-matching/

Comment: Thank you for the link. but they define "matching in a Bipartite Graph" as a set of the edges chosen in such a way that no two edges share an endpoint. 
but in my case I have for example edge [I1,A] and [I2,A] that share the same endpoint "A"


an other remark : in my problem i have the first part {I1, I2, I3} and the second part{{A,B,C,D},{A,E},{F}}
I am looking for the best combinaison that could provide I1 and I2 and I3

Comment: @hajarelmaghraoui I still don't get what you are looking for, first of all, don't we have a bipartite graph here? One part is {i1, i2, i3 .....}, the other part is {A, B, C, D, ....}